# Dnsmasq does not resolve alias on Ubuntu 18 clients

Tags: 18.04, dnsmasq

Upgrading a few machines from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 made me realize  Ubuntu 18 cannot resolve the aliases I have configured in dnsmasq.

## /etc/dnsmasq.conf

```
[...]
# Include another lot of configuration options.
#conf-file=/etc/dnsmasq.more.conf
#conf-dir=/etc/dnsmasq.d
conf-file=/etc/dnsmasq_alias.conf
[...]
```

## /etc/dnsmasq_alias.conf

```
# cat dnsmasq_alias.conf 
# Provide an alias for a "local" DNS name. Note that this _only_ works
# for targets which are names from DHCP or /etc/hosts. Give host
# "bert" another name, bertrand
# NOTE: It is important to set FQDN to CNAME: cname=bug.domain.name,bugzilla
cname=ci.company.intranet,git-lab
cname=gitlab.company.intranet,git-lab
cname=invoice.company.intranet,prod-db-inv-01
```

On Ubuntu 16, If I ping `gitlab` or `gitlab.company.intranet` it works, however it does not if do the same in Ubuntu 18.

Since it has been working and works normally on both Windows and Ubuntu 16.04 servers, I am thinking this could be something related to Ubuntu's new version (18.04)?

Dnsmasq runs on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same issue. I don't know the real cause or a better fix, but I found that it's possible to workaround by adding the domain to the alias target in dnsmasq. It's not ideal, but at least it's a central change rather than every DNS client.

So in your case, instead of

```
cname=ci.company.intranet,git-lab
```

Try

```
cname=ci.company.intranet,git-lab.company.intranet
```